# File not found error while trying to compile a java program using type 4 driver of tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to compile a Java program (`CallableStatementEx1.java`), but when I try to compile it it gives error in command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\system32>set path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;

C:\Windows\system32>set classpath = C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\ojdbc14.jar;

C:\Windows\system32>javac CallableStatementEx1.java

javac: file not found:CallableStatementExt1.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options"
```

Here is what I have done:

1. Installed JDK 8 and Tomcat 7.0
2. Copied `ojdbc14.jar` in `lib` folder of tomcat
3. Changed value of "Path" in user variables to the JDK `<bin>` folder in environment variables
4. Tried to compile the program directly without referring type4 driver as class (didn't work , the file didn't compile... it needs some libraries from the type4 driver
5. Created a batch file to compile, written as follows:

   ```
   set path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;
   set classpath = C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\ojdbc14.jar;
   javac CallableStatementEx1.java
   java CallableStatementEx1
   pause
   ```

but I still get the error shown above.

Comment: I somehow doubt that CallableStatementEx1.java is located in C:\windows\system32. You have to `cd` into the correct folder.

Comment: Add Markdown formatting to improve readability

Answer (score 0):

`javac: file not found:CallableStatementExt1.java` means the java compiler was not able to find the file CallableStatementExt1.java, which is the java file you intend to compile. Most likely the issue is, that your current directory is `C:\Windows\system32` and should be the directory, that contains the .java file instead. You could also just give the full path of the file to javac instead, but I strongly suggest you put no .class, .java and no batch files in `C:\Windows\system32`, as this is a special directory for windows.